# How can I upgrade PHP on a jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: ipad, ipod-touch, jailbreak, webserver, php

I have an iPod touch running iOS 4.0 and an iPad running iOS 4.3.1, both jailbroken. They have lighttpd and PHP installed, however PHP seems to be an old version that I need to upgrade to use a WebSocket script.

How would I go about updating it? According to a `phpinfo()` call, it has been configured with parameters to do with iOS, would this matter?

**Update 20/7/11** You can find my phpinfo at [this tinypaste](http://tinypaste.com/77682e).

Thanks in advance for all of your help. Ad@m

Comment: Can you give us your current output of phpinfo? Maybe http://pastie.org/ it.

Comment: @zevlag I've added the link to a tinypaste of my phpinfo in the question. Ad@m

Comment: thekirbylover, i am a PHP developer. Just curious to ask why you install PHP on iPad and iPod? are you able to program on these devices?

Comment: @kimsia, it's a great way to test code when I don't have a computer or access to the internet.

Comment: @thekirbylover sounds like a good idea. what about webserver, mysql?

Comment: @kimsia, I use lighttpd (the only httpd available in Cydia). There's a MySQL package, but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build the iPhone toolchain in you local environment, you can compile PHP locally and then move it to iOS.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001510/compile-php-with-gd-for-iphone-os-4-1

http://george.insideiphone.com/index.php/iphone-toolchain/

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/

http://www.sj99.com/toolchain.html

I've not done this, but I'm curious, and will make an attempt myself over the next few days, and update this answer as I go along.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this method tonight and I will tell you how I go. Ad@m

Comment: Ok... I tried it on my device and when I run `./configure` from the folder I extracted php's source code to, I get a message saying it couldn't find `gcc`. On installing from Cydia, I am told `libgcc` wasn't found. I haven't tried installing a toolchain yet, but I will try that now. Ad@m

Comment: I still haven't tried installing the keychain, but the bounty ends tomorrow so I will give it to you. Thanks for all your help for my question. Ad@m

Comment: Thanks Adam, I've not tried it yet either.  I'll hopefully get time some evening this week.